# Eloquent query to get property and its respective count?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query,

```
      $countries = Table::select('country')
           ->where('country', '!=', 'null')
           ->where('country', '!=', '')
           ->distinct('country')
           ->pluck('country');
```

But this just returns an array of all distinct countries. I'm looking for a count of each. For instance, I'd like an object such as,

```
[
    { 'country': 'US' => 'count': '23' },
    { 'country': 'FR' => 'count': '8' },
    .   .   .   . etc...
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `'country', '!=', 'null'` is not the right way to achieve `NULL` comparisons in DB queries. You will need to use `whereNotNull()` which gets converted to `IS NOT NULL` in raw SQL.
- You would also have to use `groupBy()` by `country` and `DB::raw()` in your `select` statement to get those results.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$countries = Table::select(['country',DB::raw('count(country) as `count`')])
                   ->whereNotNull('country')
                   ->where('country', '!=', "''")
                   ->groupBy('country')
                   ->get()->toArray();

dd($countries);
```

Comment: The script just died with no feedback. I changed `DB::raw` to `MyTableName::raw`, but that returned ```"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list' (SQL: select `country`, `` as `` from `article_authors` where `country` is not null and `country` !=  group by `country`)"```

Comment: @MikeK I just made an update on the where condition, see if it works. Also, it will be `DB::raw()` always and not `MyTableName::raw`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $countries = Table::select('country')
       ->where('country', '!=', 'null')
       ->where('country', '!=', '')
       ->distinct('country')
       ->sum('country') 
       ->pluck('country');
```